# Oil change & resealing of oil pan

Tags: oil-change

OK I got my oil change and my 1000 100,000 mile service and from that they told me I needed to re-seal my oil pan because it had a leak I had to pay $523 and it turns out that $328 went to labor for resealing my oil pan can’t the mechanics reseal my oil pan while they’re doing my oil change or can they charge me separately for the service. They charged me 127 for the 100k service on labor and 328 for the resealing of my oil pan. Is this right?

Comment: How many miles? Anyway, re-sealing an oil pan is not a part of a standard oil change. There is a drain plug in the pan that is supplied for doing an oil change. So, yes the labor for resealing the pan is separate. As for the values, can't say as rates change between countries and locations in countries.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I have never heard of "resealing " an oil pan unless it had been removed. Once I had an Olds intake manifold leak but Olds had saved money by not putting in a gasket at the factory.I have replaces several pan gaskets because they had been removed.

Comment: One must be careful not to overtighten pan bolts as this will cause a leak. Has anyone ever retightened these bolts ?

Answer (score 1):

The fact they charged you to reseal the oil pan separate from the oil change does make sense. Realistically from the numbers you quote, I think they gave you a pretty good price considering the work involved. I cannot tell you if the work absolutely needed to be done or not, as I was not there to witness what was going on. From what you've explained, as long as the work needed to be done, I'd say it seems reasonable. This would indicate about 2-3 hours worth of labor for the oil pan. Some vehicles are a lot more extensive than this, requiring a lot of work to get it done.